# Windows server Task scheduler start powershell that starts powerBI

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

Old situation: I have a .bat file that copies some files and then starts a powershell with a given script. This script will boot up PowerBI and will do some query and exporting then from PowerBI.
This works fine when fired up by taskscheduller when a user is logged on and only locked their PC.

Current situation: I'm moving to a Windows server instead of a separate computer with Windows desktop. I copied the task to the server and changed it to "run whether user is logged on or not".

I noticed if I force "run" on the task scheduler, it runs is some hidden mode (although I did not check the Hidden checkbox) so I don't see PowerBI get started. I assume it doesn't, as my powershell script fails further along the line where it needs to find its data in powershell.

```
log_message "***********************************************"
log_message "Executing PBI_Exporter.ps1 at $($executionDate)"
log_message "Launching Power BI"

$template = "C:\LiveData\Eisen.pbix"
$PBIDesktop = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"    


$app = START-PROCESS $PBIDesktop $template -PassThru
log_message "Waiting $($waitoPBD) seconds for PBI to launch"
Start-Sleep -s $waitoPBD

log_message "Assuming PBI is launched and ready now"

$pathtofile = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users -Filter msmdsrv.port.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1).FullName
$port = gc $pathtofile
$port = $port -replace '\D',''
$dataSource = "localhost:$port"
$pathtoDataBase_Name = $pathtofile -replace 'msmdsrv.port.txt',''
$Database_Name = Get-ChildItem -Path $pathtoDataBase_Name -Filter *.db.xml -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
$Database_Name = $Database_Name.ToString().Split(".") | select -First 1
```

I can confirm the powershell script at least gets executed, as I can see the log file getting created, and it runs till the message where it assumes PowerBI is launched. Right after that I get an error *Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.* so I **assume** that it's null because powerBI isn't executed.

Is there some way to confirm this (maybe some try/catch blocks?) and/or solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This ...

```
$app = START-PROCESS $PBIDesktop $template -PassThru
```

Will never run, because you are not calling it in your code anywhere.

Why are you sending a standard PowerShell one-Liner to a variable?

That line is not normal and should be just this...

```
START-PROCESS $PBIDesktop $template -PassThru
```

Lastly, when running external exe's from PowerShell, there are things that must be considered and in place, for them to work. See...

> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [Execution of External Commands in PowerShell Done Right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> [See also about Redirection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) 
>   [powershell-pipe-external-command-output-to-another-external-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220933/powershell-pipe-external-command-output-to-another-external-command)

Comment: the reason to put it in a variable (that works fine) is to be able to actually stop the application later on by calling "Stop-Process $app.Id"